# USING Case to determine if col1 or col2 is returned to a Temp Table in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, case

I am trying to use a `CASE` statement within a stored procedure to select either `datecolumn1` or `datecolumn2`.

I then need to select other columns and insert them into a temp table for a compliance expiry report.

I have the following

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Rangefrom DATE,
            @Rangetill DATE

    SET @Rangefrom = DATEADD(day, -50, GETDATE()) 
    SET @Rangetill = DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())

    CREATE TABLE #TempStatusTable
    (
         STATUSDATE DATE,
         NAME VARCHAR(50),
         Rangefrom DATE,
         Rangetill DATE,
         StatusID VARCHAR(10)
    )

    SELECT 
        statusdate = (CASE 
                         WHEN P.enddate IS NOT NULL 
                            THEN (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, P.EndDate, 103)
                                  FROM Applicants AS A 
                                  LEFT JOIN Person AS PE ON A.ApplicantId = PE.PersonID
                                  LEFT JOIN Placements AS P on PE.PersonID = P.Applicantid)
                         ELSE (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, A.statusdate, 103) 
                               FROM Applicants AS A 
                               LEFT JOIN Person AS PE ON A.ApplicantId = PE.PersonID
                               LEFT JOIN Placements AS P on PE.PersonID = P.Applicantid) 
                      END)
    SELECT                                      
        PE.Personname + ' ' + PE.Surname [Name],
        @rangefrom [Expiry warning from],
        @rangetill [Expiry warning till],
        A.Statusid
    INTO 
        #TempStatusTable 
    FROM  
        Applicants AS A 
    LEFT JOIN 
        Person AS PE ON A.ApplicantId = PE.PersonID
    LEFT JOIN 
        Placements AS P on A.applicantid = P.Applicantid

    SELECT * 
    FROM #TempStatusTable
```

I know this isn't correct but struggling to see where I am going wrong, is there a better way to provide this data?

Comment: Please specify database you're using in tags

Comment: Hi @VadimKotov thanks for coming back, I forgot to add the SQL tag :)

Comment: Are you using MS SQL? Please specify your database in tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `case` as flow control, it's an expression.
Try this instead:

```
SELECT statusdate = CONVERT(DATE, CASE WHEN P.enddate IS NOT NULL THEN P.EndDate ELSE A.statusdate END, 103)
FROM Applicants AS A 
LEFT JOIN Person AS PE ON A.ApplicantId = PE.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Placements AS P on PE.PersonID = P.Applicantid
```

Or shorter, using `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT statusdate = CONVERT(DATE, ISNULL(P.enddate, A.statusdate), 103)
FROM Applicants AS A 
LEFT JOIN Person AS PE ON A.ApplicantId = PE.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Placements AS P on PE.PersonID = P.Applicantid
```

Both options requires that `A.statusdate` is of the same data type as `P.enddate`, or at least can be implicitly converted to it.

Comment: Ah that is where I was going wrong, Thank you @ZoharPeled, very much appreciated!